# The password in the database still stored as a text

Tags: c#, hash, passwords

I want to store a password in the database, but when I click `Submit` button, it added successfully to the database, but it does not stored the password in the database as random text, but as the original text. How could I fix this?

Here is the code that I am using:

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=..\db1.accdb";

        string myPassword;

        string strHashedPassword;

        string strStoredPassword;

        int mySalt;

        bool checking = false;

        public Registration()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Registration_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.textBox1.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot be empty", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }

            else
            {
                Checking _checking = new Checking();
                _checking.ShowDialog();

                checking = true;
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.textBox1.Text == "" || this.textBox2.Text == "" || this.textBox3.Text == "" || this.textBox4.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot be empty", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }

            else
            {
                AddDatabase(sender, e);
            }
        }

        private void AddDatabase(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checking.Equals(false))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have to check first", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }

            else
            {
                string query = "INSERT INTO [Member] ([Username], [Password], [UserType], [UserStore]) VALUES (@Username, @Password, @UserType, @UserStore)";
                OleDbConnection _conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

                _conn.Open();

                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, _conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters["@Username"].Value = this.textBox1.Text;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters["@Password"].Value = this.textBox2.Text;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserType", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters["@UserType"].Value = this.textBox3.Text;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserStore", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters["@UserStore"].Value = this.textBox4.Text;

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    DialogResult _dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Added Successfully", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                    if (_dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        this.Hide();

                        CreateRandomPassword();

                        this.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void CreateRandomPassword()
        {
            // Generate a new random password string
            myPassword = this.textBox2.Text;

            // Generate a new random salt
            mySalt = Password.CreateRandomSalt();

            // Initialize the Password class with the password and salt
            Password pwd = new Password(myPassword, mySalt);

            // Compute the salted hash
            // NOTE: you store the salt and the salted hash in the database
            strHashedPassword = pwd.ComputeSaltedHash();

            strStoredPassword = strHashedPassword;
        }
```

Thank you!

Your answer much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your "AddDatabase" function, change  textbox value to "strStoredPassword"

like below

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters["@Password"].Value = strStoredPassword;
```

Comment: no, when I changed to `strStoredPassword`, the error shows: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Parameter @Password has no default value.`

Comment: there are many option to encrypt password,any reason you use your current method? my suggestion is to use Crypto.HashPassword(this.textBox2.Text) ,Crypto in  namespace System.Web.Helpers

Comment: @Kaoru - Have you tried my suggestion in the other answer, which also involved moving the CreateRandomPassword() call to before the query execution?  Otherwise, you're trying to insert a null value.

Comment: @Taegost: Yes, i already tried it and the error shows like the previous one. `An unhandled ....`

Comment: @Kaoru - In that case, we need to see what's inside your Password class, as it's got to be something in there.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `this.textBox2.Text` for the @Password portion of the query, but your CreateRandomPassword() method only changes strStoredPassword and strHashedPassword (As an aside, I don't really see why you have 2 variables to hold the same value, it's redundant).

You should change

`cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters["@Password"].Value = this.textBox2.Text;`

to

`cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
 cmd.Parameters["@Password"].Value = strStoredPassword;`

and move the call to CreateRandomPassword() up above the query execute.